# python with pandas to parse dates like "0001-11-29 13:00:00 BC"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to read some sql data using pandas library and one of the column "customer_date" has values like "0001-11-29 13:00:00 BC". My query fails with error

> ValueError: year 0 is out of range

Please suggest a way to parse such date/timestamps.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

session = ah.get_boto_session()
db = get_connection() **### Custom method**

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
query = "SELECT customer_date FROM customer"
df = pd.read_sql(query, db, parse_dates=["customer_date"])
print(df.head())

db.dispose()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d4e334c3f39c> in <module>()
 22 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
 23 query = "SELECT customer_date FROM customer"
---> 24 df = pd.read_sql(query, db, parse_dates=["customer_date"])
 25 print(df.head())

ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_sql(query, db, parse_dates={"customer_date": {"errors": "ignore"}})` ?

Comment: yes, tried with as well. same error.

Comment: What is 0001 ? Is it the year value ? Can you add couple of more samples of the date values. Is`0001` in all the date values you have?

Comment: and what about using your custom format e.g. `parse_dates={"customer_date": {"format": ....` or just as-is, without `parse_dates` parameter and then transform it yourself?

Comment: can you do something like `select case when customer >= '1970-01-01' then customer else '1970-01-01 end from customer`? to kind of lower clip this column

Comment: yes, '0001' is year value. One other values is '0001-12-29 14:00:00 BC'. dont have many examples. @Ben.T your approach will work but i was wondering if there is another way may be with another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

session = ah.get_boto_session()
db = get_connection() **### Custom method**

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
query = "SELECT case when customer_date >= '1970-01-01' then customer_date else '1970-01-01' end AS customer_date FROM customer"
df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
print(df.head())

db.dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant read that date in pandas datetime library
if you try pd.to_datetime("0001-11-29 13:00:00"), pandas will raise an out of bounds exception

you should use dates grater than 1676

Maybe what you need is to replace the year in your sql statement

Comment: can you tell how u mean?